# Eclipse Juno and Maven plugin fails with project update

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-3

I am having this problem for long time . I have red error image on all my projects.
In problem window it displayed

> Project configuration is not up-to-date with pom.xml. Run Maven->Update Project or use Quick Fix.

when right click and click update project and error popup displayed saying,

> An internal error occurred during: "Updating Maven Project".
>   org/eclipse/m2e/wtp/WTPProjectsUtil

anybody knows how to fix this problem, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from preferences>type 'wtp' > deselect all option then build and clean again

Comment: are you sure 'wtp', when I  type wtp nothing is listing in the window.

Comment: it seems problem with m2e plugin ... how do you create the project ? .. with maven archetype or from eclipse> maven project ?

Comment: Also try (0) having updated version of m2e(1) Disable the maven nature for the project (via the right-click menu) (2)run mvn eclipse:clean (while your project is open in eclipse) (3) re-enable the maven nature.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Eclipse? I got this error in RAD 8.5 (based on Exlipse 3.6.3). You might just need to back rev your m2e plugin. See the answers to this question: [NoClassDefFoundError org.eclipse.m2e.wtp.WTPProjectsUtil upon Maven build Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18123210/noclassdeffounderror-org-eclipse-m2e-wtp-wtpprojectsutil-upon-maven-build-eclips)

I followed the link to the [developer works forum](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=9c08ac4c-87f4-43e2-a1c1-0f300f5246c6#7f0e9100-7038-4142-bb2d-877d1813d42a) and chose the 2nd option presented there:

- assuming you have m2e 1.4 (from [release-for-indigo repository](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/m2e-users/msg04198.html))
- uninstall m2e-wtp 1.x version
- and install m2e-wtp 0.18.0 (from [p2 juno snapshot repo](http://download.eclipse.org/m2e-wtp/snapshots/juno))

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat similar solution suggested by "pppeater" - below is for Eclipse Juno

- Remove all the jars starting with "org.eclipse.m2e." from eclipse/ide/plugins folder
- From your Eclipse Market Place search for "m2e-wtp" - install "Maven Integration for Eclipse WTP (Juno) 1.0.1
- Restart your eclipse and select your project and do "Update Maven dependencies (Alt+F5)"